# Definición ambigua en herencia pero con parámetros distintos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-view-controller

Buen día!

Acudo a ustedes porque llevo bastante tiempo rabiando con un tema que debería ser sencillo, pero me está volviendo loco..

El caso, es que yo tengo un `Controller` llamando `TransformadorController` el cual tiene varias funciones, entre ellas una definida como

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Agregar (NuevoTrafoViewModel formulario)
{
  //Código
}
```

Ahora, trabajo con otro `Controller` llamado `DistribucionController` que hereda de `TransformadorController`

En algunos casos, tuve que sobreescribir métodos de `TransformadorController` y no tuve problema, pero el conflicto se dió en la siguiente función

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Agregar(NuevoDistribucionViewModel form)
{
//Código
}
```

La cuestión, es que al querer ingresar a esta segunda función se genera la siguiente excepción;

> La solicitud actual para la acción 'Agregar' en el tipo de controlador
>   'DistribucionController' es ambigua entre los métodos de acción
>   siguientes: 
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]
>   Agregar(DBTrafos.ViewModels._Transformador.Distribucion.NuevoDistribucionViewModel)
>   en el tipo DBTrafos.Controllers.DistribucionController
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]
>   Agregar(DBTrafos.ViewModels.NuevoTrafoViewModel) en el tipo
>   DBTrafos.Controllers.TransformadorController

Lo que me resulta extremadamente extraño, es que como puede verse en el código, y en la misma excepción, ambos métodos reciben objetos de clases distintas, por lo que no debería generarse conflicto por lo que entiendo.

¿Alguien sabe a que puede deberse este conflicto?

Muchísimas gracias!

**EDIT**

Dejo el código de lo último que intente (con ayuda de **hardkoded**)

```
public new async Task<ActionResult> Agregar(ViewModels.NuevoTrafoViewModel form) => null;
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Agregar(NuevoDistribucionViewModel form)
        {
            //lógica

            return View();
        }
```

**NuevoDistribucionViewModel**

```
public class NuevoDistribucionViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Código delfos")]
        public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Primer cliente")]
        public string cliente { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Primera nota de venta")]
        public string nv { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Observaciones")]
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }


        public List<SelectListItem> ListaSubTipo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Tipo de transformador")]
        public int id_subtipo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La potencia es obligatoria.")]
        [DisplayName("Potencia")]
        public decimal? potencia { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Tensión mayor")]
        public decimal? tension_mayor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Tensión menor")]
        public decimal? tension_menor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Material de arrollamiento mayor")]
        public string material_mayor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Material de arrollamiento menor")]
        public string material_menor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Grupo de Conexiones")]
        public string GrupoDeConexiones { get; set; }

        public ConexionadoViewModel conexionadoviewmodel { get; set; }

        //************************************************************//
        //************************REGULACIÓN**************************//
        //************************************************************//


        [DisplayName("Tensión")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        public decimal? Reg_primaria_tension { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (+)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        public int? Reg_primaria_puntos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (-)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        public int? Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (+)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        [Range(0, 9999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "El número puede tener un máximo de 2 decimales.")]
        public decimal? Reg_primaria_porcentaje { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (-)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos))]
        public decimal? Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Frecuencia")]
        public int frecuencia { get; set; }

    }
```

**NuevoTrafoViewModel**

```
public class NuevoTrafoViewModel
    {

        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El código delfos puede tener un máximo de 50 caracteres.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo código delfos es obligatorio!")]
        [DisplayName("Código Delfos")]
        public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Tipo de Máquina")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El tipo de transformador es obligatorio!")]
        public int? id_tipo_trafo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tipos_Trafo { get; set; }

        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "El campo cliente puede tener un máximo de 50 caracteres!")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo cliente es obligatorio!")]
        [DisplayName("Primer Cliente")]
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Lista_Cliente { get; set; }


        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "La nota de venta puede tener un máximo de 10 caracteres.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La nota de venta es obligatoria!"), DisplayName("Primer Nota de Venta")]
        public string Nota_de_venta { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Observaciones")]
        public string observaciones { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Norma")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Es obligatorio seleccionar una norma!")]
        public string norma { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Lista_Normas { get; set; }


        //Potencias
        [DisplayName("Potencia Mayor")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d+(\,\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Potencia, máximo 2 decimales.")]        
        [Required (ErrorMessage = "La potencia primaria es un campo obligatorio")]
        public decimal? pot_primaria { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Potencia Intermedia")]
        public decimal? pot_secundaria { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Potencia Menor")]
        public decimal? pot_terciaria { get; set; }

        //Tensiones
        [RequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(pot_primaria), ErrorMessage = "Debe definir la tensión mayor si la potencia mayor fué definida.")]
        [DisplayName("Tensión Nominal Mayor")]
        public decimal? tension_primaria { get; set; }

        [RequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(pot_secundaria), ErrorMessage = "Debe definir tensión intermedia si la potencia intermedia fué definida.")]
        [DisplayName("Tensión Nominal Intermedia")]
        public decimal? tension_secundaria { get; set; }

        [RequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(pot_terciaria), ErrorMessage = "Debe definir tensión menor si la potencia menor fué definida.")]
        [DisplayName("Tensión Nominal Menor")]
        public decimal? tension_terciaria { get; set; }

        //Tensiones Alternativas.
        [DisplayName("Tension Alternativa Mayor")]
        public decimal? tension_alternativa_primaria { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Tensión Alternativa Intermedia")]
        public decimal? tension_alternativa_secundaria { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Tensión Alternativa Menor")]
        public decimal? tension_alternativa_terciaria { get; set; }


        //materiales
        [RequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(pot_primaria), ErrorMessage = "Este campo es obligatorio si la potencia mayor fué definida.")]
        [DisplayName("Material de Arrollamiento Mayor")]
        public string arrollamiento_primario { get; set; }

        [RequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(pot_secundaria), ErrorMessage = "Este campo es obligatorio si la potencia intermedia fué definida.")]
        [DisplayName("Material de Arrollamiento Intermedio")]
        public string arrollamiento_secundario { get; set; }

        [RequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(pot_terciaria), ErrorMessage = "Este campo es obligatorio si la potencia menor fué definida.")]
        [DisplayName("Material de Arrollamiento Menor")]
        public string arrollamiento_terciario { get; set; }

        //Grupo de Conexionado.

        [DisplayName("Grupo de Conexión")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Es obligatorio definir un grupo de conexiones.")]
        public string GrupoConexion { get; set; }

        public ConexionadoViewModel conexionadoviewmodel { get; set; }

        //Frecuencia.
        [DisplayName("Frecuencia")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La frecuencia es un campo obligatorio.")]
        public int? Frecuencia { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El número máximo de caracteres es 50!")]

        [DisplayName("Frecuencia Variable")]
        public string Frecuencia_Variable { get; set; }


        //Regulaciones
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Lista_Regulacion_Porcentajes
        {
            get
            {
                return Listas.GetPorcentajePuntos().OrderBy(x => x.Text);
            }
        }

        [DisplayName("Tensión")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        public decimal? Reg_primaria_tension { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (+)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension),nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos),nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje),nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        public int? Reg_primaria_puntos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (-)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        public int? Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (+)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo))]
        [Range(0, 9999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "El número puede tener un máximo de 2 decimales.")]
        public decimal? Reg_primaria_porcentaje { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (-)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_primaria_tension), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_primaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos))]
        public decimal? Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo { get; set; }


        //************************************************************//
        //********************SEGUNDA REGULACIÓN**********************//
        //************************************************************//

        [DisplayName("Tensión")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje_negativos))]
        public decimal? Reg_secundaria_tension { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (+)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_secundaria_tension), nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje_negativos))]
        public int? Reg_secundaria_puntos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (-)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_secundaria_tension), nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje_negativos))]
        public int? Reg_secundaria_puntos_negativos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (+)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_secundaria_tension), nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje_negativos))]
        public decimal? Reg_secundaria_porcentaje { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (-)")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_secundaria_tension), nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_secundaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_secundaria_puntos_negativos))]
        public decimal? Reg_secundaria_porcentaje_negativos { get; set; }

        //************************************************************//
        //********************TERCERA REGULACIÓN**********************//
        //************************************************************//

        [DisplayName("Tensión")]
        [CustomRequiredIfNotEmpty(nameof(Reg_terciaria_puntos_negativos), nameof(Reg_terciaria_puntos), nameof(Reg_terciaria_porcentaje), nameof(Reg_terciaria_porcentaje_negativos))]
        public decimal? Reg_terciaria_tension { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (+)")]
        public int? Reg_terciaria_puntos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Puntos (-)")]
        public int? Reg_terciaria_puntos_negativos { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (+)")]
        public decimal? Reg_terciaria_porcentaje { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Porcentaje por punto (-)")]
        public decimal? Reg_terciaria_porcentaje_negativos { get; set; }

        //Constructor
        public NuevoTrafoViewModel() {
            conexionadoviewmodel = new ConexionadoViewModel();
            id_tipo_trafo = null;
                                     }

        #region Métodos para obtener las listas y que no las cargue siempre si no son necesarias.

        //Función que llena el combo de Normas.
        public void ObtenerListaNormas(string a = null)
        {
            Lista_Normas = DBTrafos.Helpers.Listas.GetNormas();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
            {
                (from p in Lista_Normas where (p.Text == a) select p).First().Selected = true;
            }
            //return Lista_Normas;
        }

        //Función que llena this.Tipo_Trafo.
        public void ObtenerTipoTrafo()
        {

            /*using (DBTrafosContext db = new DBTrafosContext())
            {
                Tipos_Trafo = (from p in db.Tipo_Transformador
                        orderby p.Subtipo
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) p.ID)).Trim(),
                            Text = p.Subtipo


                        }).ToList();                                
            }

            if (id_tipo_trafo == null)
            {
                Tipos_Trafo = Tipos_Trafo.Concat(new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Seleccione una Opción --", Value = "0", Disabled = true, Selected = true } });
                Tipos_Trafo = Tipos_Trafo.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Value == "0").ThenBy(x => x.Text);
            }*/
        Tipos_Trafo = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }



        public void obtenerTodo()
        {
            ObtenerListaNormas();
            ObtenerTipoTrafo();

        }

        public Transformador devolverModeloTrafo()
        {
            Transformador trafo = new Transformador();

            trafo.Codigo_delfos = this.Codigo_delfos;
            trafo.id_tipo_maquina = this.id_tipo_trafo;
            trafo.Cliente = this.Cliente;
            trafo.Nota_de_venta = this.Nota_de_venta;
            trafo.Observaciones = this.observaciones;
            trafo.Norma = this.norma;
            trafo.Potencia_Primaria = this.pot_primaria;
            trafo.Potencia_Secundaria = this.pot_secundaria;
            trafo.Potencia_Terciaria = this.pot_terciaria;
            trafo.Tension_nominal_primaria = this.tension_primaria;
            trafo.Tension_nominal_secundaria = this.tension_secundaria;
            trafo.Tension_nominal_terciaria = this.tension_terciaria;
            trafo.Tension_alternativa_primaria = this.tension_alternativa_primaria;
            trafo.Tension_alternativa_secundaria = this.tension_alternativa_secundaria;
            trafo.Tension_alternativa_terciaria = this.tension_alternativa_terciaria;
            trafo.Mat_arrollamiento_primario = this.arrollamiento_primario;
            trafo.Mat_arrollamiento_secundario = this.arrollamiento_secundario;
            trafo.Mat_arrollamiento_terciario = this.arrollamiento_terciario;
            trafo.GrupoConexion = this.GrupoConexion;
            trafo.Frecuencia = this.Frecuencia;
            trafo.Frecuencia_Variable = this.Frecuencia_Variable;

            //Regulación Primaria
            trafo.Reg_primaria_tension = this.Reg_primaria_tension;
            trafo.Reg_primaria_puntos = this.Reg_primaria_puntos;
            trafo.Reg_primaria_porcentaje = this.Reg_primaria_porcentaje;
            trafo.Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos = this.Reg_primaria_puntos_negativos;
            trafo.Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo = this.Reg_primaria_porcentaje_negativo;

            //Regulación Secundaria
            trafo.Reg_secundaria_tension = this.Reg_secundaria_tension;
            trafo.Reg_secundaria_puntos = this.Reg_secundaria_puntos;
            trafo.Reg_secundaria_porcentaje = this.Reg_secundaria_porcentaje;
            trafo.Reg_secundaria_puntos_negativos = this.Reg_secundaria_puntos_negativos;
            trafo.Reg_secundaria_porcentaje_negativos = this.Reg_secundaria_porcentaje_negativos;

            //Regulación Terciaria
            trafo.Reg_terciaria_tension = this.Reg_terciaria_tension;
            trafo.Reg_terciaria_puntos = this.Reg_terciaria_puntos;
            trafo.Reg_terciaria_porcentaje = this.Reg_terciaria_porcentaje;
            trafo.Reg_terciaria_puntos_negativos = this.Reg_terciaria_puntos_negativos;
            trafo.Reg_terciaria_porcentaje_negativos = this.Reg_terciaria_porcentaje_negativos;

            return trafo;
        }

        #endregion



    }
```

Comment: Si hay alguna parte del código que sea de utilidad ver, si me escriben en los comentarios lo edito rápido, intente poner lo menos posible para que sea mas legible

Comment: No soy experto ni mucho menos en asp.net-mvc, pero creo recordar que asp.net no soporta métodos con el mismo nombre. Prueba a cambiar el nombre del segundo método, y añadirle justo encima `[ActionName("Agregar")]`

Comment: @Pikoh muchas gracias por la respuesta, ahí lo intente y no hubo caso che, sigue lanzando la misma excepción

Comment: Puede ser que NuevoDistribucionViewModel herede de NuevoTrafoViewModel?

Comment: @hardkoded Gracias por la respuesta; no, no hereda de NuevoTrafoViewModel

Comment: ¿puedes poner las clases 'NuevoDistribucionViewModel ' y 'NuevoTrafoViewModel '?

Comment: @Luis ahí agregué el código de las dos clases

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es ocultar el método de la clase padre utilizando el modificador [new](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier):

```
public new Task<ActionResult> Agregar (NuevoTrafoViewModel formulario) => null;
```

Comment: Primero que nada muchísimas gracias, intenté lo que me dijiste y se produce la misma excepción :(

Comment: mmm probé tu mismo ejemplo localmente y funcionó

Comment: Agregaste esto en DistribucionController?

Comment: Lo agregue, ahí edite la respuesta, quedó de esa manera

Answer (score 0):

A nivel objetos lo que estas haciendo funciona sin problema, como mencionas por tener metodos que reciben diferentes parametros.

A nivel **MVC** existe el conflicto por que el ruteo del MVC no sabe cuál de los dos métodos usar, no sabe si convertir los datos recibidos mediante POST en un objeto **NuevoTrafoViewModel** o en un objeto **NuevoDistribucionViewModel**.

Si necesitas conservar el mismo nombre de accion en tu controlador te recomendaria utilizar las palabras reservadas virtual y override de la siguiente manera:

En tu **Transformador Controller** agregas virtual:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Agregar (NuevoTrafoViewModel formulario)
{
  //Código
}
```

En tu **DistribucionController** agregas override:

```
[HttpPost]
public override async Task<ActionResult> Agregar(NuevoDistribucionViewModel form)
{
//Código
}
```

Cuando agregas virtual a tu método de tu clase base estas diciendo que ese metodo funciona pero que si tu clase hija necesita un comportamiento diferente puedes sobreescribirlo.

De esa forma en tu clase hija al agregar override estas **sobreescribiendo** la implementación de tu clase base.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Lamentablemente no puedo usar `override` porque tienen una sobrecarga distinta, lo intente y no hubo caso

Answer (score -1):

En tu DistribucionController utiliza un verbo diferente como PUT:

```
[HttpPut]
public override async Task<ActionResult> Agregar(NuevoDistribucionViewModel form)
{
//Código
}
```